# How can I create Woodmart theme "linked variations" through REST API?

Tags: posts, themes, post-meta

I want to create and call linked variables via REST API.
Woodmart theme itself has created a post type named "woodmart_woo_lv". And this type of post has three private meta fields named:

```
_woodmart_linked_products
_woodmart_linked_attrs
_woodmart_linked_use_product_image
```

I make a POST request to this endpoint and send these values:

`POST /wp-json/wp/v2/woodmart_woo_lv/`

```
{
    "title": "This is title",
    "type": "woodmart_woo_lv",
    "status": "publish",
    "meta": {
        "_woodmart_linked_products": ["4666","4696"],
        "_woodmart_linked_attrs": "pa_color",
        "_woodmart_linked_use_product_image": false
    }
}
```

Linked variables are also created, but the values I put in the meta field are not applied. where is the problem from?